# had limped vs had been limping

Tags: past-perfect, past-perfect-continuous

> "There were drops of blood on the floor, it looked as if a small wounded creature **had limped** through the stall."

Could you say:

> “There were drops of blood on the floor, it looked as if a small wounded creature **had been limping** through the stall"

without any difference in meaning?

Comment: I believe they are functionally equivalent. The only "difference" is in the pacing of the sentences—the first seems more "active" to me.

Comment: I get the feeling this must be a duplicate question; I feel like some variant of this gets asked almost weekly.

Comment: @J.R. I get the feeling that English tenses are a surprisingly tricky thing.    Maybe we should have some kind of canonical post for it (beyond the one about the perfect, which I think already exists).

Comment: I couldn't agree more. The difficulty is not so much understanding the meaning but feeling the nuance, which you can't always learn from a book.

Comment: @stangdon - I have had those same thoughts: (a) this must be vexingly tricky, and (b) there ought to be a canonical post to help explain it.